# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int error

Tags: java, arrays

I am tying to compile a white loop for a set of arrays, but am getting the following error:

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int

Here is what I have:

```
package PayrollPractice;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

//Payroll Class, pg 504

public class Payroll 
{
    private int[] _emp;         //employee ID
    private int[] _hours;           //hours worked
    private double[] _rates;        //rate of pay
    private double[] _wages;        //wages

    public Payroll() 
    {
        //array of employee ID(s)
        _emp = new int[] { 5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 7580489 };
    }

    public boolean is_emp(int number)
    {
        int index,          //loop control variable
            _emp;           //element the value is found at
        boolean found;      //flag indicating the search results

        //element 0 is the starting point of the search, pg 463
        index = 0;

        //Store the default values for the element and found, pg 463
        _emp = -1;
        found = false;

        //search the array, pg 463
        while (!found && index < _emp)
        {
            //does this element have a value?
            if (_emp[index] == number)       //ERROR: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else {
                //increment index so we can look at the next element
                index++;
            }

        }

        //return either the subscript of the value(if found)
        //or -1 to indicate the value was not found.
        return found;   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a top-level variable named _emp which is an array.

You then **hide** that variable by having another variable with the same name inside a method. That variable is an int. Either rename one of your variables, or use the **this** keyword to explicitly refer to the top-level variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...no idea what you are talking about though.

Comment: Which part confused you? Did you google the words I bolded?

Answer (score 1):

There are two variables called `_emp` in your program. One is a class field of type array and the other is a local variable of type int inside a method. If you want to access the one of type array, you need to use `this._emp` where `this` references the class object.

Answer (score 0):

You declare this:

```
private int[] _emp;
```

and assign this:

```
_emp = -1;
```

That's not right, is it?

Please do lose that awful C++ underscore to denote private class members.  Awful code to look at.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
public class Payroll {
    private static final int[] DEFAULT_EMPLOYEES = {5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 7580489};

    private int[] emp;             //employee ID

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Payroll payroll = new Payroll();
        for (String arg : args)  {
            System.out.println(String.format("employee ID: %s is employee? %b", arg, payroll.isEmployee(Integer.parseInt(arg))));
        }
    }

    public Payroll() {
        this(DEFAULT_EMPLOYEES);
    }

    public Payroll(int[] emp) {
        if (emp != null) {
            this.emp = new int[emp.length];
            System.arraycopy(emp, 0, this.emp, 0, emp.length);
        }
        this.emp = emp;
    }

    public boolean isEmployee(int number) {
        int index = 0;
        while (index < this.emp.length) {
            if (this.emp[index] == number) {
                return true;
            }
            ++index;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's something else to think about while you're learning.  Instead of multiple arrays, encapsulate all that info into an Employee class.  Then have a List or array of Employees.

```
public class Employee {
    private int number;
    private int hoursWorked;
    private double payPerHour;

    public Employee(int n, int h, double r) {
        this.number = n;
        this.hoursWorked = h;  // negative allowed?  I'd guess "no"
        this.rate = r;  // negative allowed?  I'd guess "no"
    }

    public double getWages() { 
        return this.hoursWorked*this.payPerHour;  // don't set it; calculate it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor also is not closed; you need an }.

Comment: Constructor?  Sorry for being a noob, but I can't tell the difference between constructors, mutators, accessors, etc...about the only thing I understand is System.out.println("");.